# How to recovery node smoothly in Nifi 1.9.2 and Zookeeper 3.x?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

There are 3 Node running in Nifi.However,the one of them is lost suddenly,and the log shows that the local flows are different from cluster flows.I wanna pick the formerly successful solution that to delete the flow.xml.gz of the failed Node and restarting it.

I am not sure whether the data in failed Node would loss?Any help is appreciated!
Why the node would lost?I post the logs as followed.

```
2020-08-20 08:17:33,019 ERROR [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Handling reconnection request failed due to: org.apache.nifi.controller.UninheritableFlowException: Failed to connect node to cluster because local flow is different than cluster flow.
org.apache.nifi.controller.UninheritableFlowException: Failed to connect node to cluster because local flow is different than cluster flow.
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromConnectionResponse(StandardFlowService.java:1026)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.handleReconnectionRequest(StandardFlowService.java:668)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.access$200(StandardFlowService.java:109)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService$1.run(StandardFlowService.java:415)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.controller.UninheritableFlowException: Proposed configuration is not inheritable by the flow controller because of flow differences: Found difference in Flows:
Cluster Fingerprint contains additional configuration from Local Fingerprint: 655b3f59-6f5c-1d8d-0000-0000002a2398NO_VALUENO_VALUENO_VERSION_CONTROL_INFORMATION655b3f67-6f5c-1d8d-ffff-ffffc31d8b7eNO_VALUENO_VALUENO_VERSION_CONTROL_INFORMATION75b74aab-1e43-3e6d-88e9-6ce5936703a4
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:315)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.synchronize(FlowController.java:1368)
    at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.load(StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.java:88)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:812)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromConnectionResponse(StandardFlowService.java:1001)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```